# How can I make this ImageBrightener method function properly?

Tags: java, arrays, image, for-loop, multidimensional-array

This ImageBrightener method is supposed to brighten the image by increasing the color values. Each value should increase half the distance between it and 255. Thus, 155 would go to 205 while 205 would go to 230 and so on. Can anyone help figure out the issue with ImageBrightener! Thanks

```
import squint.SImage;
public class ImageBrightener implements ImageTransformer {

    @Override
    public SImage transform(SImage picture) {
        return BrightenImage(picture);
    }

    private static SImage BrightenImage(SImage si) {
        int[][] newReds = BrightenImageSingleChannel(si.getRedPixelArray());
        int[][] newGreens = BrightenImageSingleChannel(si.getGreenPixelArray());
        int[][] newBlues = BrightenImageSingleChannel(si.getBluePixelArray());

        return new SImage(newReds, newGreens, newBlues);
    }

    // Here is the code to brighten the image and is not functioning properly
    private static int[][] BrightenImageSingleChannel(int[][] pixelArray) {
        private static int[][] BrightenImageSingleChannel(int[][] pixelArray) {
            int columns = pixelArray.length;
            int rows = pixelArray[0].length;
            int[][] answer = new int[columns][rows];
            for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
                    answer[x][y] = 255 - pixelArray[x][y] ;
                    answer[x][y] = answer[x][y] + pixelArray[x][y] ;
                }
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }

    // Here is the properly functioning code for darkening my image.
    private static int[][] DarkenImageSingleChannel(int[][] pixelArray) {
        int columns = pixelArray.length;
        int rows = pixelArray[0].length;
        int[][] answer = new int[columns][rows];
        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
                answer[x][y] = (255 * 2) / 3 - pixelArray[x][y];
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
answer[x][y] = 255 - pixelArray[x][y] ;
answer[x][y] = answer[x][y] + pixelArray[x][y] ;
```

`answer[x][y]` will always be 255.

Try this

```
answer[x][y] = (pixelArray[x][y] + 255) / 2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't realize that `answer[x][y]` will always be 255.